# Why does my code write a blank file when I try to redirect Console output to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, console, windows-services

I've written a "Windows Service" version of a Console application.  Since the Console isn't visible, I want to redirect the text that would appear on the Console to a file.

To this end, I've written the following code:

```
private void SetupConsoleLogging()
{
    string logFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFileName"];
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(logFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
    Console.SetOut(streamWriter);
}
```

The above code is invoked at the beginning of a Windows Service.  However, this just results in a blank file being created.

Assuming that there isn't an error in the program or some other problem causing it to fail (nothing appears in the Event Viewer), what could be preventing the output from being written to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try to set the property of your StreamWriter like this:

```
streamWriter.AutoFlush = true;
```

It will flush the buffer to the underlying stream after it calls to StreamWriter.Write.

Comment: I think that this should be a comment in response to @Jay's answer.

Comment: Well, it's true.@DanielAllenLangdon

Comment: I apologize.  I must have been asleep when I read your answer.  It is a separate solution.  I was mixed up.

Comment: It's OK. @DanielAllenLangdon

Comment: +1 your answer is much better than mine.  Thanks for pointing out StreamWriter.AutoFlush.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx) (or [`Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx)) your `StreamWriter` to write out your data:

```
streamWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Any easy way to make this happen automatically so that the output is written to the file immediately each time `Console.WriteLine` is encountered?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon If you don't want to use a logging framework I believe `TraceListener` with the `Trace.AutoFlush` property set to true will do what you want.